# How to tell Java run this Runtime.getRuntime().exec, without waiting what ever command it has to run, simply run it in backend?

Tags: java, linux, swing

How to let the Runtime.getRuntime().exec(p) run without waiting for the sleep 10??
Currently its wrong, its waiting until the exec gets complete and then moves to next. Where i need to on the fly let the exec running so that after 10 second later it can kill the PresentationInProjector.jpg.

```
Example:

   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("(sleep 10; echo '09|00|CC|01|83|88' | nc localhost 58888) &");
   PlayThisSlideShow("PresentationInProjector.jpg");
```

Comment: Print timestamp before and after `exec()` - I guess that it is not waiting 10s on this line.

Comment: calling exec is not a blocking call You have a problem somewhere else.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the docs [`exec()`:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29)

> Executes the specified string command in a separate process.

So any call to `exec()` should not block unless you used `waitFor()` on the returned process of the `Runtime` .

Here is a small example(Exception handling omitted):

```
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c ping 127.0.0.1 -n 10");

System.out.println("Here 1");//this will execute immediately

try {

    p.waitFor();

    System.out.println("Here 2");//this will only be seen after +- 10 seconds and process has finished

} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running this code? JVM will be still running as long as subprocess is running. `exec()` is not blocking current thread and your code does exactly the same thing as the code in the question.

Comment: @PiotrGwiazda yes I checked that hence my edit. But the OP says its blocking. Maybe he is mistaken

Comment: @David Kroukamp: it worked like the way you have given. But i need to add more instead of that Runtime line: https://gist.github.com/3810155

Comment: You have `p.waitFor();` in the example. This is what is waiting for the end of subprocess.

Comment: @YumYumYum Im confused is the problem solved? If not what is the new problem? "i need to add more instead of that Runtime line" like what?

Comment: @DavidKroukamp: see Piotr Gwiazda comment, its working but in anyway it will be waiting. But its working like you have given and others are saying. I just needed to use my seperate function because i have long argument for parsing

Answer (score 5):

`exec()` is not making thread wait until spawned process ends by default. You need to call `process.waitFor()` explicitly to make current process wait.
I guess that `PlayThisSlideShow("PresentationInProjector.jpg");` is being called immediately after `exec()`. What you see is system making JVM process be running as long as child process is running. I guess there is no way to overcome this easily, to have parent process killed while child process still running.

Why can't you kill presentation projector from Java?

Answer (score 3):

```
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("(sleep 10; echo '09|00|CC|01|83|88' | nc localhost 58888) &");
```

will not do what you expect. `Runtime.exec` is not a shell and doesn't understand things like `()` grouping, `;` or `|`. But the actions you're trying to perform can be done purely in Java, you don't need to exec an external process. For example (exception handling omitted):

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    Thread.sleep(10000); //sleep 10
    Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 58888); // nc
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
    pw.print("09|00|CC|01|83|88\n"); // echo
    pw.close();
    s.close();
  }
}).start();
```