# Executing methods one after another and one at a time

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface

I want to execute a number of methods inside a button,but some take less time and some take more time to process and I want them to run them in a particular sequence as one method works on another methods output.My button execution is as follows:-

```
{
Basic b = new Basic();
b.method1(); //Normal processing
b.method2(); //Normal processing
b.method3(); //Heavy  processing takes a lot of time like 5 to 10sec
b.method4(); //Basic  processing
b.method5(); //Medium Processing FileHandling(works on 5 file)
}
```

So what happens is that everything goes perfect and as excepted up-till execution of method2 but as comes the method3 it gets all messed up.So I things what happens is that my method3 gets skipped and method4 and method5 gets executed ended up giving me a null pointer exception as they depends on the data received from the execution of method3.

Can someone tell me how I can make sure that my methods 4 and 5 runs only after my method3 is finised,and FYI my method3 contains 2 methods from different class one that makes some scripts and another which executes it which take the real time since it uses bash shell.

P.S.-as my button execution is finished I see that my method3 has not done anything like it's have been skipped or something.

Code:-

```
public void method3(String abstarpath,String filename,String parapth)
{
    try{
    String cmd1 = "tar xzf "+abstarpath;
    String cmd2 = "mv "+ parapth+"/"+filename +" /home/apoorv/Desktop/";
    txtarea.append("#"+cmd1+"\n");
    txtarea.append("#"+cmd2+"\n");
    executeCommands(cmd1, cmd2);            
    }catch(Exception e){
        txtarea.append("#"+e+"\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    txtarea.append("\n");
}

public void executeCommands(String cmd1,String cmd2) throws IOException {

    File tempScript = createTempScript(cmd1,cmd2);

    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash", tempScript.toString());
        pb.inheritIO();
        Process process = pb.start();
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        txtarea.append("#"+e+"\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        tempScript.delete();
    }
}

public File createTempScript(String cmd1,String cmd2) throws IOException {
    File tempScript = File.createTempFile("script", null);

    Writer streamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(
            tempScript));
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(streamWriter);

    printWriter.println("#!/bin/bash");
    printWriter.println(cmd1);
    printWriter.println(cmd2);
    printWriter.close();

    return tempScript;
}
```

Comment: If your observation is correct, then there must be some concurrency going on inside the method3 code. Check for Thread creation or something in that direction. Then check out if you can wait for it to finish.

Comment: unless `method3` is asynchronous, it should work as you want it to - `method4` should start after `method3` is done. it sounds like there might be a problem in `method3`, can you post its contents?

Comment: so why does these method not executing sequentially?

Comment: thank you all.....I tried using synchronized() and aslo thread.join to make sure that my thread finishes first although I am not sure if I executed it correctly can anybody show me how to execute multithreading in this.

Comment: @SabirKhan That's exactly what OP is asking ...

Comment: @Ap00rv No we cannot. You need to show more of your code in method3.  How to handle this depends heavily on what you are doing there.

Comment: By the way: If there is heavy processing involved, you should not execute any of this on the EDT. Make an asynchronous method that does it all on a background thread. To avoid that the button is hit again in the meantime, you can disable it while the task is running. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

Comment: The shown code snippet calls all methods in a _sequential_ way - one after the other. Unless those methods have no threading involved, the code will work as you expect. But if there is some threading involved, some portions of the code could run _concurrently_. This highly depends on the code inside those methods. So show their code (or maybe the important parts of their code). Otherwise, we can't help you.

Comment: @user5226582 I can post the content of the method3 but it contains another method which contains another each contain 10-15 line.So thats why I didn't post them but I can tell you that my first method in method3 creates a script to tar a file and it executes the script using another method which runs java Runtime to execute it via shell and we know that tar command can take time to execute.

Comment: Does the method wait for the external command to finish? Please add that specific peace of code.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12668943/982149

Comment: I have updated the Post please take a look @Fildor

Comment: Hmm, `waitFor` _should_ block until the Process is done ... I do not see an obvious error.

Comment: hey....thank you all for your time you all were right the code should work as expected,I just found out that I my tar script is not working as expected now that I have fixed it everything is working just fine..

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, the problem you're having does not seem to have anything to do with concurrency. The problem is that your main method does not know whether the `methodX()` methods finished successfully.

What you can do is move the exception handling to your main method:

```
try {
    Basic b = new Basic();    
    b.method1(); //Normal processing
    b.method2(); //Normal processing
    b.method3(); //Heavy  processing takes a lot of time like 5 to 10sec
    b.method4(); //Basic  processing
    b.method5(); //Medium Processing FileHandling(works on 5 file)
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // error handling
}
```

(And of course, you have to remove the exception handling from your other methods).

Then, as soon as one of the methods throws an exception, the rest of the methods is skipped and the exception handler executed.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you out

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            return Method1();
        }).ContinueWith((t) => {
            return Method2(t.Result.ToString());

        }).ContinueWith((p) =>
        {
            return Method3(p.Result.ToString());
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

        Console.ReadLine();           
    }

    public static string Method1()
    {
        for(int i =0;i<20;i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(400);
            Console.WriteLine("Working in Method1");
        }
        return "return from method1";

    }
    public static string Method2(string input)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(600);
            Console.WriteLine(input + " to Method 2");
        }
        return "Input from Method2";
    }
    public static string Method3(string input)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(300);
            Console.WriteLine(input + " to Method 3");
        }
        return "Input from Method3";
    }
}
```